# Kendo: Convert decimal time to TimeSpan

Tags: kendo-ui

I'd like to format the Billable and Non Billable hours on grid from decimal to time. Lets say if the time is 3.5, the grid it should show 03:05 that is the format I would like to have. Thanks

[image: Kendo grid]

Comment: Kendo supports formating datetime but the initial data has to be a datetime. Maybe you can convert the decimal into time using JavaScript and from there when you want to display de value on the grid you can use format: {..} in the column definition to show the converted time as you like.

Comment: What if you can handle it at c# side and bind it over here.

Comment: 3,5 decimal converted to hours shouldn't´t be 03h30m ?

Comment: @Carlos Martins; Yes